# How to scrape elements with no class or id from a website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a selenium project. In the project, I am trying to scrape a particular element from the website. The element has no class or ID associated with it. So I am kind of stuck on how to extract that detail.

This is the [website](https://www.target.com/p/hawaiian-punch-fruit-juicy-red-1-gal-bottle/-/A-13051948)

In the website, if you look at the HTML markup for specifications, there is a `div` with contents `<b>Form</b>: Liquid`. I want to extract the 'Liquid'.

this is my code so far

```
def extract():
            
    form_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[text()='Form']/")))
    form_text = form_element.text
    return form_text
```

This is resulting in a `TimeOutException`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

PS: I was able to click the `show more` button on the page to display the specifications area with selenium. Just in case you are wondering, that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `div` parent from the elements you want using this xpath:

`//b[text()='Form:']//parent::div`

And to grab the text it seem like you have to using **`.get_attribute('innerHTML')`** instead of **`.text`**

Try following code:

```
def extract():
    form_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[text()='Form:']//parent::div")))
    form_text = form_element.get_attribute('innerHTML').split("</b>",1)[1]
    return form_text
```

Answer (score 1):

When we try to get elements by locators ID is unique ones, if you dont have Id You can go with class name ,xpath and linktext

Use this xapth:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Liquid')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting to `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` {say if you are using chrome and you have webdriver for chrome installed} and writing the next line as; `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")` [say if you wanted to extract details about h1 element and use that element.].Hope i understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value `Liquid` you need to click on `Show more` button first and then wait for `visibility_of_element_located()` for the element on the page.You can use following approach to get the value.

Using `Split`()

```
driver.get("https://www.target.com/p/hawaiian-punch-fruit-juicy-red-1-gal-bottle/-/A-13051948")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-test='toggleContentButton' and contains(.,'Show more')]"))).click()
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[./b[text()='Form:']]"))).text.split("Form:")[-1])
```

Using `Java Scripts Executor`

```
driver.get("https://www.target.com/p/hawaiian-punch-fruit-juicy-red-1-gal-bottle/-/A-13051948")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-test='toggleContentButton' and contains(.,'Show more')]"))).click()
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[./b[text()='Form:']]")))))
```